# Mysqli_fetch_array no locaweb, erro ao fazer login!

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php   
session_start();

require_once('conecta.php');    
$email = sha1($_POST['email']);
$senha = $_POST['senha'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM dados WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'";
$objDb = new db();
$link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();    
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if ($resultado) {
    $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
    if (isset($dados['email'])) {

        $_SESSION['email'] = $dados["email"];
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $dados["nome"];



        header('Location: indexVol.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: entrar.php?erro=1');


    }
} else {
    echo 'Erro na execução da consulta, favor entrar em contato com o admin do site';
}
?>
```

Porém quando tento fazer login, ela vai direto para `header('Location: entrar.php?erro=1');`, como se no banco de dados não tivesse o email e senha cadastrado, porém tem. Alguém tem alguma ideia de o que pode estar errado? Eu sei que o código não está seguro a sql injection, mas isso é só um teste pra mim entender.

Obs.: A página está hospedada no `locaweb.com`, não sei se lá o `mysqli_fetch_array` está disponível pra uso, porque pelo Xampp funciona normalmente!

Comment: Vamos fazer uma depuração nisso, antes do seu if($resultado) adicione echo mysqli_num_rows($resultado); e verifique quantas linhas sua query retornou! Em seguida poste aqui.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão Ele não retorna erro, eu pedi um `var_dump($resultado)` e ele retorna apenas `object(mysqli_result)#3 (0) { }`

Comment: Se ele não retorna nenhuma linha quer dizer que não existem registros com o login e senha digitados. Se você usa o sha1 para salvar o password na tabela na hora do login deve pegar a senha inserida e converter para sha1. Apesar de ter dito deixo claro que esse código seu é inseguro!

Comment: Mas existe o registro, eu mudei, tirei o sha1 do código, fiz o cadastro de novo, e o `var_dump($resultado)` continua vindo vazio, mesmo tendo o registro no banco!

Comment: @RafaelSalomão Eu descobri qual era o erro, olhei no log no diretório da hospedagem, e tava com um erro em outra página, por causa do session. Porque no locaweb é preciso mudar o local de armazenamento das session, e eu não tinha feito isso na página que o usuário é redirecionado após o login! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Show Arthur, mas dá uma olhada no stack  tem muitos exemplos para montar o login seguro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro no inicio do código pode esta gerando o erro, onde vc usa **SHA1** no e-mail, onde o correto e no e-mail:

errado:

```
<?php   
 session_start();

 require_once('conecta.php');    
 $email = sha1($_POST['email']);
 $senha = $_POST['senha'];
```

correto:

```
<?php   
 session_start();

 require_once('conecta.php');    
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $senha = sha1($_POST['senha']);
```

Comment: Realmente não tinha visto isso, porém mudei e continua não fazendo o login!

Comment: o erro é o mesmo ou mudou?

Comment: Continua a mesma coisa, ele pula direto como es não tivesse os dados de login no banco!

Comment: tem como vc dar um var_dump($resultado)  e ver o que aparece?

Comment: vc pegar a query montada ($sql ) e jogar direto no banco de dados, retornar o resultado esperado?

Comment: Ele retorna `object(mysqli_result)#3 (0) { }`, e se eu pegar a query montada direto no banco ele retorna o esperado!

Comment: Eu descobri qual era o erro, olhei no log no diretorio da hospedagem, e tava com um erro em outra página, por causa do session. Porque no locaweb é preciso mudar o local de armazenamento das session! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Modifique essas linhas:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = sha1($_POST['senha']);
```

Comment: Eu modifiquei, porém continua dando erro, eu pedi um `var_dump($resultado)` e ele retorna apenas `object(mysqli_result)#3 (0) { }`

Comment: Você pode editar o post e colocar a sua função conecta_mysql() ?

Comment: Eu descobri qual era o erro, olhei no log no diretório da hospedagem, e tava com um erro em outra página, por causa do session. Porque no locaweb é preciso mudar o local de armazenamento das session, e eu não tinha feito isso na página que o usuário é redirecionado após o login! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!